# Geometric progression using Python / Pandas / Numpy (without loop and using recurrence)

Tags: python, math, numpy, pandas

I'd like to implement a geometric progression using Python / Pandas / Numpy.

Here is what I did:

```
N = 10
n0 = 0
n_array = np.arange(n0, n0 + N, 1)
u = pd.Series(index = n_array)
un0 = 1
u[n0] = un0
for n in u.index[1::]:
    #u[n] = u[n-1] + 1.2 # arithmetic progression
    u[n] = u[n-1] * 1.2 # geometric progression
print(u)
```

I get:

```
0    1.000000
1    1.200000
2    1.440000
3    1.728000
4    2.073600
5    2.488320
6    2.985984
7    3.583181
8    4.299817
9    5.159780
dtype: float64
```

I wonder how I could avoid to use this for loop.

I had a look at 
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trique
and found that u_n can be expressed as: u_n = u_{n_0} * q^{n-n_0}

So I did that

```
n0 = 0
N = 10
n_array = np.arange(n0, n0 + N, 1)
un0 = 1
q = 1.2
u = pd.Series(map(lambda n: un0 * q ** (n - n0), n_array), index = n_array)
```

That's ok... but I'm looking for a way to define it in a recurrent way like

```
u_n0 = 1
u_n = u_{n-1} * 1.2
```

But I don't see how to do it using Python / Pandas / Numpy... I wonder if it's possible.

Comment: How about `un0 * 1.2 ** np.arange(N)`? It is not recursive, though.

Comment: That's easier than what I've written... but not recursive. Thank you anyway. With Pandas Series it looks like `u = pd.Series(un0 * q ** np.arange(N), index=n_array`. I'm still looking for a recursive solution (without for loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it works for me in a Pandas series:

```
N = 10
n0 = 0
n_array = np.arange(n0, n0 + N, 1)
u = pd.Series(index = n_array)
u[n0] = 1
q = 1.2
# option 1:
u = pd.Series(u[n0]*q**(u.index.values - n0), index = n_array)
# or option 2 with cumprod
u[1:] = q
u = u.cumprod()
```

Comment: If you want to stick with `pandas` , based on answer from @Jaime you can replace the last line with, `>>> u[1:] = q    >>> u= u.cumprod()`

Comment: `u = pd.Series(u[n0]*q**(np.array(u.index) - n0), index = n_array)`
should fix that

Comment: Very good.  Using `np.cumprod` is the fastest method I could find other than using a generator (which requires a generator and a for loop)

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility, that is probably more computationally efficient than using exponentiation:

```
>>> N, un0, q = 10, 1, 1.2
>>> u = np.empty((N,))
>>> u[0] = un0
>>> u[1:] = q
>>> np.cumprod(u)
array([ 1.        ,  1.2       ,  1.44      ,  1.728     ,  2.0736    ,
        2.48832   ,  2.985984  ,  3.5831808 ,  4.29981696,  5.15978035])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The cumprod idea was very good. @Ashish solution use Pandas Series... which is what I was requesting. I upvote you solution and mark Ashish 's solution.

Comment: @working4coins I don't do Pandas, so I am not sure of the details, but `Series` is built on top of the `np.ndarray`, so it has to have a `.cumprod()` method that you can use for this.

Answer (score 9):

Use `numpy.logspace`

```
>>> import numpy
>>> N=10
>>> u=numpy.logspace(0,N,num=N, base=1.2, endpoint=False)
>>> print u
[ 1.          1.2         1.44        1.728       2.0736      2.48832
  2.985984    3.5831808   4.29981696  5.15978035]
```

Comment: Interesting solution. You should do `>>> N, un0, q = 10, 5, 1.2 
>>> u = pd.Series(un0 * np.logspace(0, N, num=N, base=q, endpoint=False), index = n_array)
u` in order to be able to set un0

Comment: This is very neat.  But for some reason it's 50 to 100 times slower than the other solutions.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Just defining `u(u0, q, n)` function should work:

```
def u(u0, q, n):
    return u0 if n==0 else q*u(u0, q, n-1)
```

Comment: I want this geometric progression in a Pandas Series

Comment: May be, list comprehension: `[u(1, 1.2, n) for n in range(10)]`? But it's like "hidden for loop."

Comment: Yes it's an hidden for loop. I run %timeit in an IPython notebook. Results for `N, n0, un0, q = 200, 0, 1, 1.2` - `100 loops, best of 3: 5.59 ms per loop` with list comprehension and `10000 loops, best of 3: 96.9 µs per loop` with `np.logspace` @ilmarinen solution

Answer (score 0):

Itertools helps:

```
from itertools import accumulate
import operator
import pandas as pd

d, f, n = 1.2, 1, 10  # degree, first element, number
pd.Series([* accumulate([f]+[d] * (n-1), func = operator.mul)])
```

result is:

```
0     1.000000
1     1.510000
2     2.280100
3     3.442951
4     5.198856
5     7.850273
6    11.853912
7    17.899406
8    27.028104
9    40.812437
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Ashish's solution with `np.cumprod` is the simplest but if you are willing to define a generator somewhere then this is probably the most computationally efficient solution:

```
def geometric_series_generator(x, r, n):
    """Generate a geometric series of length n, starting
    at x and increasing by the ratio r.
    """

    for i in range(n):
        yield x
        x = x*r

N = 10
u0 = 1
r = 1.2
gen = geometric_series_generator(u0, r, N)
geom_series = np.fromiter(gen, float, count=N)
print(pd.Series(geom_series, index=np.arange(0, N, 1)))
```

Output:

```
0    1.000000
1    1.200000
2    1.440000
3    1.728000
4    2.073600
5    2.488320
6    2.985984
7    3.583181
8    4.299817
9    5.159780
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This came out at 2.2 µs on my computer for a series of length 10,000 whereas the cumprod method was about 5.15 µs.